# IBM FEB 8.6 REST API for getting single record fails

Tags: java, rest, websphere-portal, ibm-forms

I am getting following error when hitting FEB REST API for getting record. I am passing Authorization header and using get request using following URL and I am using Java for calling the REST API.

If I am hitting same URL using postman, it works perfectly.

**URL : http://localhost/forms-basic/secure/org/data/f0720c16-d4b8-442f-8674-2d7fbdab8afc/F_Form1/8d4dfeed-aa11-45fc-a958-23d62d9328cc**

```
[3/10/16 6:37:57:293 GMT] 000000bd StandardExcep E com.ibm.form.nitro.platform.StandardExceptionMapper toResponse 1b6b206a-248c-4a4f-bb45-6bad1ee45b29
                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.form.nitro.endpoints.data.DataEntryPoint.getFormat(DataEntryPoint.java:1636)
    at com.ibm.form.nitro.endpoints.data.DataEntryPoint.getRecord(DataEntryPoint.java:965)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.form.platform.service.rest.jaxrs.model.RESTMethod.invoke(RESTMethod.java:345)
    at com.ibm.form.platform.service.rest.jaxrs.impl.RESTApplicationImpl._process(RESTApplicationImpl.java:1194)
    at com.ibm.form.platform.service.rest.jaxrs.impl.RESTApplicationImpl.restProcess(RESTApplicationImpl.java:391)
    at com.ibm.form.platform.service.rest.jaxrs.impl.RESTApplicationImpl.process(RESTApplicationImpl.java:355)
    at com.ibm.form.nitro.endpoints.RESTEntryPoint.performView(RESTEntryPoint.java:294)
    at com.ibm.form.platform.impl.dispatcher.simple.SimpleDispatcher.performServletWork(SimpleDispatcher.java:395)
    at com.ibm.form.platform.impl.front.internal.java.FrameworkJavaAccess.performServletWork(FrameworkJavaAccess.java:370)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.form.platform.front.access.servlet.SimplifiedPlatformAccessServlet.service(SimplifiedPlatformAccessServlet.java:85)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:461)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:528)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:314)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have passed **accept** header as **application/atom+xml** in the request header, and now it is working fine, without any issues.